# extracting data from specific content type

Tags: migrations, backups

I have an old site developed with drupal 7 and now I have created a new site (with new template) with drupal 8. I want to extract a specific content type data and restore in the new site. suppose I have a content type called Academic and I want to restore it on the new site. Is it possible to do that automatically, because it has more than 1000 contents. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom migration for that node type - see https://www.drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2016/04/drupal-6-drupal-81x-custom-content-migration (more than you need for just the one migration, but it should help).